# Yii2 загрузка фото шаблон advanced

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2

Всем привет!
Можете подсказать куда правильно загружать фото из админки шаблона advanced?
Я загружаю по такому пути: common/uploads/images/news/96377ebfbe69fd6b50c259016c549fca.jpg

мне нужно чтобы я фотографии мог выводить и на frontend и на backend
Скорее всего нужно переписать .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*common* тут не при чем.

Сохраняйте в *frontend/web/uploads*. На *frontend/web/uploads* сделайте символьную ссылку. Как вариант, можно на бекэнде выводить картинки с фронтэнда.

Символьные ссылки назначаются примерно так:

```
ln -s /var/www/site/frontend/web/uploads /var/www/site/backend/web/uploads
chown -h user:group /var/www/site/backend/web/uploads
```